# Automated JWT API Troubleshooting

Tags: c#, jwt

I'm trying to programmatically use an API that isn't necessarily open to the public. I've taken my iPhone and intercepted the traffic to watch the traffic to and from and have managed to ALMOST get it working.

When using an iPhone the following traffic flow occurs:

```
phone ---> api   (client_auth request with client_id)
api   ---> phone (replies with token)

phone ---> api   (use token to request a password challenge)
api   ---> phone (replies salts and bcrypt algo)

phone ---> api   (send encrypted credentials using supplied salt)
api   ---> phone (replies with attestation request challenge)

phone ---> api   (sends attestation challenge response)
api   ---> phone (sends 12 hour JWT token)
```

When I use my C# code to perform the same requests:

```
c#code ---> api   (client_auth request with client_id)
api   ---> c#code (replies with token)

c#code ---> api   (use token to request a password challenge)
api   ---> c#code (replies salts and bcrypt algo)

c#code ---> api   (send encrypted credentials using supplied salt)
api   ---> c#code (sends 1 hour JWT token)
```

Any idea what is happening and why I don't get the attestation request with my c# code?

Comment: Are you calling the API endpoint with the correct signature for returning the attestation? The fact it returns a different temporal value for the token would imply there's multiple code paths.

Comment: @melkisadek I do sign the content with a key that is available online, but perhaps you are correct. Their code has a <cient_id:key> embedded in it, but perhaps I'm not seeing another key or its not available. I'm not very familiar with JWT or this entire process, so sorry if this question isn't very good.

Comment: @melkisadek you are correct. I was signing with the incorrect key.  thank you!

Comment: @melkisadek Any idea how this response got created? - Received object:
{"type":"attestation-required","challenge":"MBVnf9WVZmOv8TLCuotXIxdPcwymDhJ8RLSFm5Jt8bA=","key_id":"gBT72JYLZBQWpzvQLFKvcEr6l6vvT3DhOG2VARS4Xvk=.3Wx2vpyPvdJSasguw10UZwwGveaRq7Hn3QHLW+p2j70=","expires":1653443814}

{"type":"attestation","attestation":"omlzaWduYXR1cmVYRzBFAiBI51FvT\/Ca9Dn4viPh\/6+m3UwV+EWt0U25pE0rBOseXQIhAJepc1\/EvMNUv\/yiRE7UiqFAy64PgIKXpsoiw1rQDIHTcWF1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3JEYXRhWCUxWnWOj9mp26uquoKJoo8FSK4kGnZUY2ZYPl2AGoKDGkAAAAAI","key_id":"3Wx2vpyPvdJSasguw10UZwwGveaRq7Hn3QHLW+p2j70="}

Comment: @melkisadek ran out of room. first object was the response from my password challenge. Second object is the response from the iPhone client to the API.  Not sure how they calculated that attestation value.

Comment: You'd be better adding those to the question with formatting. I'm not sure how the responses got created. Without access to the API documentation I'm guessing all you have is trial and error?